# Pandas dataframe max in a group based on conditions on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, pandas-groupby

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before. In a pandas dataframe I have data like

```
    A    B    C

1   z    0    0
2   z    1    1
3   z    2    2
4   y    0    0
5   y    1    1
6   z    2    2.5
7   z    0    0
8   z    1    0.2
9   z    2    0.8
```

I would like to get

```
    A    B    C

1   z    2    2.5
2   y    1    1
3   z    2    0.8
```

In the above example(from first table) z went from 0 for B and C to 2 for B and 2.5 for C respectively before going to 0 for B and C. One important property is B and C can be different however they will go to 0 at the same time. Think of it as a counter, when device is off all your counters will go back to 0. The devices in above example being y and z.

Also from the first table you can also see y went from 0 to 1 for both B and C respectively however they never went back to 0 but I still need the maximum which is 1 and 1 for B and C.

I can write some python code to loop through and do the necessary transformations but I was wondering if this is possible with some pandas magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses vectorized methods all the way through and should be pretty quick.

Add a column with value `1` when there is a 'reset' of the counter, by checking where both B & C are 0.

```
df['new_sample'] = (df[['B','C']] == 0).any(1).astype(int)
```

Then, groupby the device type, and using the cumulative sum of the `new_sample` column, create a counter for which trial of each device each row represents.

```
df['sample'] = df.groupby('A')['new_sample'].cumsum()
```

Finally, you can group by the device and sample number and take the maximum.

```
In [85]: df.groupby(['A', 'sample'], as_index=False)[['B','C']].max()
Out[85]: 
   A  sample  B    C
0  y       1  1  1.0
1  z       1  2  2.5
2  z       2  2  0.8
```